# Is MFC is based on any design pattern,if so which design pattern?

Tags: design-patterns, mfc

Is MFC is based on any design pattern,if so which design pattern??

Comment: The "implement stuff using language features you only half understand, put the stuff in a big bucket and give it stir" pattern.

Answer (score 1):

It includes several, including [Model-View-Controller](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller), [Chain of Responsibility](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chain-of-responsibility_pattern) and [Factory Method](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_method_pattern).

Comment: It's a bit of a stretch to say that Document-View is the same as Model-View-Controller. The duties of Controller are intermingled into the Document and View in an ad hoc manner.

Answer (score 1):

Haven't been coding MFC for quite some time, but back in the days I believe the [Document-View pattern](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4x1xy43a(VS.80).aspx) was the "default".