# MFC - How to post a message to all views that were derived from CView class?

Tags: mfc, message

I want to post a message to all views. 
I'm considering get a Document global reference and then implement a method like below

```
void SomeAppDoc::DispatchToAll( UINT msg, WPARAM wP, LPARAM lP )
{
  //some how get all view's reference
  //iterate and update each views 
}
```

What is the effective way?

Comment: Like @ChrisN posted, GetDocument()->UpateAllViews is the effective way.

Comment: GetDocument()->UpdateAllViews() is not thread safe as I know.

Answer (score 2):

The simplest way is to call [`CDocument::UpdateAllViews`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/eys41xfw.aspx), which calls the [`OnUpdate`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w1z3te7e.aspx) function of each view attached to the document.

If you really need to post a message to each view, rather than call `OnUpdate`, do something similar to `UpdateAllViews`:

```
void SomeAppDoc::DispatchToAll(UINT msg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    POSITION pos = GetFirstViewPosition();
    while (pos != NULL)
    {
        CView* pView = GetNextView(pos);
        pView->PostMessage(msg, wParam, lParam);
    }
}
```

I hope this helps!

Comment: @webnoon If multiple threads can change the list of views attached to a document, then no this isn't thread safe.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem however I found this provided answer to be insufficient as there are two parts to a solution to this question.

The first is as provided with the process of iterating through the various views and using `PostMessage()` to send a message to each view.

The second part is what to do on the `CView` side that is receiving the message being sent and I want to provide a bit of a note on that part.

In the MFC application I am working on, I wanted to send a message to the `CView` and was running into an exception due to a mistake on my part as to how to process the message being sent.

In the class derived from `CDocument` I had a function that iterates over the list of `CView` objects to send a message to each. In this particular case I was wanting to reposition the view port to a designated section of a report. This required the Windows message that was sent to include an offset value as well as a message identifier.

```
        POSITION pos = GetFirstViewPosition();
        while (pos != NULL)
        {
            CView* pView = GetNextView(pos);
            if (pView)
                pView->PostMessage(WM_APP + 10, sectionHeader.m_ListOffset, 1);
        }
```

I am using the standard Windows SDK define `WM_APP` to create a unique message identifier within the range of user defined message ids (as opposed to standard Windows message ids) to send a message indicating the offset to use as the `WPARAM` argument of `PostMessage()`. See [Message Map Macros - ON_MESSAGE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/mfc/reference/message-map-macros-mfc?view=vs-2019#on_message) which states:

> User-defined messages are any messages that are not standard Windows
>   WM_MESSAGE messages. When selecting a message ID, you must use values
>   within the range of WM_USER (0x0400) to 0x7FFF or WM_APP (0x8000) to
>   0xBFFF. For more information regarding message IDs, see [WM_APP](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winmsg/wm-app).

In the `CView` class I added an entry to the message map for the `CView` class. I am using `ON_MESSAGE` rather than `ON_COMMAND` because I need to provide the offset to the `CView` processing the message.

```
ON_MESSAGE(WM_APP + 10, &CPCSampleView::OnWindowSetSection)
```

and then added the source for the actual message handler itself which calculates the correct viewport scroll position by using the offset of the text line in a buffer along with the line height of each text line:

```
LRESULT CPCSampleView::OnWindowSetSection(WPARAM  wParam, LPARAM  lParam)
{
    CPCSampleDoc *pDoc = GetDocument();

    CPoint  ptOrigin;
    ptOrigin = GetScrollPosition();

    wParam *= m_sizeCell.cy;    // multiple text line offset by height of each line of text
    ptOrigin.y = wParam;        // change the vertical position of the scroll bar

    ScrollToPosition(ptOrigin);   // move the scroll bar elevator

    this->UpdateWindow();     // tell view to update displayed window to match elevator position

    return 0;
}
```

For more details about messages see [Message Handling and Mapping](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/mfc/message-handling-and-mapping?view=vs-2019) in the Microsoft docs.