# Why is PostThreadMessage() giving me an unlisted error message ERROR_MESSAGE_SYNC_ONLY?

Tags: multithreading, winapi, mfc

In an MFC application that has to process user events in real time, a sub-thread is created to do some lengthy math processing.  However, sending it a message results in error 1159, which winerror.h reveals to be ERROR_MESSAGE_SYNC_ONLY.  Why?

Thread creation:

```
#define MATHTHREAD_PROC ( 1 )

hMathThread = CreateThread( 0, 0, MathThreadProc, this, 0, &dwMathThreadID );
if( !hMathThread )
    printf( "Math CreateThread() fail\n" );
```

Thread signalling:

```
if ( !PostThreadMessage( dwMathThreadID, MATHTHREAD_PROC, NULL, 0 ) ) {
    DWORD dwError = GetLastError();
    printf( "PostThreadMessage() for math thread: %d\n", dwError );
}
```

Thread  code:

```
static DWORD WINAPI MathThreadProc( LPVOID pvUserData ) {

    return ( (MyClass*) pvUserData )->MathThread();
}

DWORD MyClass::MathThread() {

    MSG msg;
    int iRV;

    // https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms644946(v=vs.85).aspx
    iRV = PeekMessage( &msg, NULL, WM_USER, WM_USER, PM_NOREMOVE );

    while ( iRV = GetMessage( &msg, 0, 0, 0 ) ) {

        if ( iRV == -1 )
            printf( "GetMessage() = -1: %d\n", GetLastError() );

        switch ( msg.message ) {

        case MATHTHREAD_PROC:
            ProcessMath();
            break;

        default:
            printf( "got math thread exit request %p\n", this );
            abort();
        }
    }

    printf( "SCGraph::MathThread(): GetMessage = WM_QUIT\n" );

    return msg.wParam;
}
```

Comment: The list of error messages an API can return is hardly ever comprehensive. In general, that list cannot even be determined, especially when an API calls code outside its control. Your code has to be prepared to deal with unknown error codes.

Comment: Show the code how you post MATHTHREAD_PROC message.

Comment: Hi Tom tom, it's the second code snippet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ERROR_MESSAGE_SYNC_ONLY means that the message is below WM_USER.  Just changing the message ID causes the post to work:

```
#define MATHTHREAD_PROC ( WM_USER + 1 )
```

Comment: You should use rather `WM_APP` than `WM_USER`. Read [this SO article](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30843497/898348)

Comment: @Jabberwocky: There are no system-defined *thread* messages in the `WM_USER` range. Calling `PostThreadMessage` with messages in the `WM_USER` range will not collide with system-defined messages. The Q&A you linked to is simply wrong (which I have hinted to in a comment already).